# stop the page scrolling when selecting/dragging text

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I have a page where I do not want the user to be able to scroll.  In order to prevent it, I just set the body to have a hidden overflow style.  This is sufficient up until the point where a user tries to select some text and then drags to the bottom.  The window then scrolls with the users dragging.  How can I prevent this?

Comment: You will get better responses if you post the current code you are using. If you can create a live example using something like http://jsfiddle.net that is even better.

Comment: I think your method is a bit flawed, if you don't want the user to see something don't show it, or if its some data you need for some weird hack use display:none css or hidden input fields. Trying to prevent basic fundamental browser functionality is recipe for usability disaster.

Comment: I apologise for my flawed method.  At some points in time, during animation, divs are scaled using CSS transforms and thus span outside of the visible area. At these moments in time the user's dragging takes them out of the desired view area.  I was just hoping there was some event that was fired during this select/drag process that I could intercept.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

use `position: fixed;`. If you want the whole body to be non-scrollable:

```
body
{
  position: fixed;
}
```

EDIT: after receiving the comment from user Sam, I've decided to go back and test this method once again.  Now that I reconsider it and Sam's concern that it would mess with styles, I've come to the conclusion that the following would be a better solution:

```
html
{
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

The prevents some sites (stackoverflow included) from ending up left aligned.  It also uses the highest node available, which should have been done in the first place.

Comment: i want to kiss you. no homo

Comment: Not quite useful for mobile, since it adds the safari address bar.

Comment: @TomRoggero Thank you for pointing that out to future developers looking for a solution to this; however, I don't think it's relavant to the question or answer.  What you're describing is a fullscreen no scrollbar set up.  That wasn't specified in the question.  If you are looking for a solution to that, please make another question rather than simply down voting this answer.

Comment: @JosephMarikle it doesn't matter if it's fullscreen or not, but in Mobile to add position fixed to the body is not cool. So your answer doesn't scale, so I thought voting it down is just fine.

Comment: @TomRoggero I don't think you understand the question.  It involves "stop[ing] the page [from] scrolling when selecting/dragging text".  Nothing of mobile is mentioned in the question. It's irrelevant to this discussion. Even the nature of the question facilitates against mobile: It involves drag selecting text, which doesn't work the same in touch environments. You can't hold to highlight and drag past the screen on iOS devices. This solution is for a unique non-mobile circumstance. If you have a better answer, post it; otherwise, read the question and realize this does not encompass mobile.

Comment: Well, it says I cannot modify my vote until you modify your answer.

Comment: @TomRoggero I don't mind the loss of rep.  If you don't want it to impact your rep I can edit it for you and comment so you can see it, but otherwise I'm actually very happy there is this discussion being here.  I only now wish there were a solution we could link or something for future developers.

Comment: T H A N K   Y O U   S O    M U C H    O M G

Comment: This is not very useful since it can mess a lot with the website's style.

Comment: @Sam I think if you want to prevent scrolling when selecting and dragging text, you are far beyond messing with website styles.  This solution has a very limited scope of use, but if you have a better solution, by all means post it.  If you do, comment back here and I'll review it and upvote it if it's a viable solution.

Comment: @JosephMarikle I agree with you that this is very limited and I am not bothered by the mobile point at all. There are still projects out there sadly enough that still require these kinds of solutions for functionality. So I posted a variant as a solution. Not saying I am able to find a better one. If i do ill update it.

Answer (score 2):

I tried Josephs answer but it can mess up a lot of the style on the website.

Another way would be to set the overflow of the website to hidden, this is also far from ideal but it didn't mess up any styling for me, hopefully this is helpful to someone.

```
body {
  overflow-y: hidden;     
}
```

Comment: This is in my opinion the more correct solution.  `overflow` deals directly with the scrolling of a page. While this doesn't correct the original poster's problem of movement while highlighting text, it should help in a lot of instances where scrolling needs prevented.

Comment: Yeah, I already mentioned this (in my question) as something I'd been using successfully until I tried selecting text.

Comment: oh my, I totally misread the question, was so busy looking for answers. Sorry my bad

Answer (score 2):

It can be helpfull

```
html
{
    overflow: hidden;

}
```

Comment: This is actually dangerous because it will hide the scrollbar and give you the false feeling that the body is non-scrollable. This won't prevent the page from scrolling when the user drags any selected text.